# Display post in visual composer with custom html

Tags: posts

Im learning the way to display post with custom html style. Because Im using VC so I wonder if there are any element that would display post by category or tag, then we can go to the function and custom its html and style?

I was working with a theme and it has something call "Popular post" and they actually can replace its shorcode to do some custom ("ww-shortcode-blog-popular") after searching for day I can't find a single document about it so it must be something specific for that theme then. Im so new please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom shortcode and then map it with vc_map(). You can read about it here: https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524332 . You can also modify already existing visual composer shortcodes https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=524294 , but I didn't tried that yet.